# Vue router cannot access root app path '/' from nested view nested children

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2, vue-router

I am trying to access root path of app '/' or named component 'Home' from nested view with nested children.

```
const routes = [
    {
        path: "/",
        name: "Home",
        component: Home,
    },
    ...
    {
        path: "/account",
        name: "Account",
        component: AccountHome,
        children: [
            {
                name: "AccountAvatars",
                path: "avatars",
                component: AccountAvatar,
            },
         ...
        ],
    },
];

const router = new VueRouter({
    mode: "history",
    base: '/',
    routes,
    scrollBehavior(to, from, savedPosition) {
        return { x: 0, y: 0 };
    },
});

Vue.use(VueRouter);

export default router;
    ....
```

When i want to use router-link or manually `this.$router.push({name: 'Home'})` or `this.$router.push({name: '/'})` from /account/avatars for example click on router-link or $router.push not working at all.

App.vue

```
<template>
    <div id="app">
        <global-header />
        <router-view />
        <global-footer />
    </div>
</template>
```

Home.vue

```
<template>
    <div class="home">    
        <offer />
        <home-menu />
        <game-catalog/>
        <benefits />
        <news />
    </div>
</template>
```

AccountHome.vue

```
<template>
    <div class="container">
        <div
            class="account"
        >
            <account-left-sidebar />
            <router-view />
            <account-right-sidebar />
        </div>
    </div>
</template>
```

Router instance

```
const router = new VueRouter({
  mode: 'history',
  base: process.env.BASE_URL,
  routes,
  scrollBehavior(to, from, savedPosition) {
    return { x: 0, y: 0 }
  }
})
```

Comment: Where do you calling router.push?

Comment: @FatimaMazhit Inside onClick handler, which is attached to <a> when not using router-link. onClick handler works, but this.$router.push in handler function body not working :(

Comment: Are sure you are calling that method? Can you share code from here?

Answer (score 0):

check what's inside `BASE_URL`. the `.base` argument of `VueRouter` constructor is not your app's baseUrl. it's just default path. [official Vue Router doc](https://router.vuejs.org/api/#base). it should be `base:'/'`.

check this working code:

https://codesandbox.io/s/holy-bush-jsi79?file=/src/routes.js

Edit: I've added programmatically routing example as well.(to match your edit)

Edit 2: I've also added another running example that's exactly same to your edit. it still works. I think one of your components are fiddling with routers.

https://codepen.io/rabelais88/pen/NWjJEMe

Comment: I already tried that(base: '/'), it is not working :(

Comment: check the example again. I've also added routing that's exactly same as yours and it still works. if it still doesn't work in your code, I think we're missing something from your writing. please give us a reproducible example.

Comment: I've also added another example that's exactly same to your edit. I think your example is missing the crucial part to solve the problem. please make a reproducible environment before posting to stackoverflow next time. I know it's frustrating for you to do so but it'll save much more time.